# Task Scheduler - Show Powershell Prompt

Tags: powershell, command-line, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0

I Know how to schedule a Powershell script, but now I'm looking for a way to show what's happening. I Don't want to write the output to a log, but I want to have a prompt opened. 
(Like running the .bat directly, without using the Task Schedular).

Google isn't helping me.

Comment: I think there is a setting `Run only when user is logged on` that forces visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Run only when user is logged on` option, per the screenshot below.

[image: Scheduled Task]

Comment: but I think the trick is in how do we do that via powershell cmd line.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Most of the time I need the run the scripts when there isn't a logged on user. But when I log on, I need to see the progress..

Comment: One way to approach this would be to use file-based logging to see the results, whether the user is logged in or not. Ex: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff687007.aspx. it doesn't exactly address the "see the results on the screen" requirement, but the text file is much more persistent across unexpected restarts, if someone is logged in but not looking at the screen, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This a late reply, but I wanted to share my experience.

Use [`New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskprincipal?view=windowsserver2019-ps), with `-LogonType Interactive`, the `-RunLevel` if you need it, and the `-UserId` to specify which user will run that task.

In addition, use [`New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=windowsserver2019-ps) with the `-AtLogon` parameter (if you want the PowerShell window to appear at logon) and set `-User` to the same as `-UserId` above.

When registering the principal with [`Register-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=windowsserver2019-ps), make sure not use the `-User`, `-Password`, and `-RunLevel` parameters, as the syntax paragraph states they are not allowed.